# Using Chart.js with Gatsby markdown

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js, gatsby

I'm trying to display a chart.js chart in a markdown generated blog post on a gatsby website.

Following the chart.js installation guide here. (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html) I've opted to import chart.js into the project as via a CDN. I'm using the bundled links which come with moment.js.

I'm using Helmet to import the chart.js library into the gatsby site.

```
<Helmet>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js">
</Helmet>
```

For now, I'm trying to display the example chart found here https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html into my markup post;

```
---
title: Title 1234
description: Subtitle 4567
category: graphs
date: "2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"
---

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>

### Title 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Pellentesque maximus eros finibus rhoncus egestas. 
Aliquam ut erat ipsum. Mauris ultricies faucibus hendrerit.
```

The result is a white canvas in my blog post with no visible chart. When I inspect the generated code I also find that the canvas has been wrapped in `<p></p>` tags. 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use MDX to do this. [Gatsby has good documentation on how to achieve this](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/mdx/).

Once implemented, you'll be able to use regular React components from your markdown content, similar to:

#### Your content file

```
// content.mdx
import { Chart } from '../components/chart'

The chart is rendered inside our MDX document.

<Chart />
```

#### Consume & render your content

```js
// index.js
import React from "react"
import { MDXProvider } from "@mdx-js/react"
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx"
import mdxContent from "./your-content.mdx"

export default () => {
    return (
        <MDXProvider>
            <MDXRenderer>{mdxContent}</MDXRenderer>
        </MDXProvider>
    )
}
```

#### Your chart component (regular React)

```js
import React from "react"
import chartjs from "chart-js"

export default () => {
  const Chart = new chartjs(...)

  return <Chart />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction man! Followed this guide to convert my gatsby site from markdown to MDX https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-11-21-how-to-convert-an-existing-gatsby-blog-to-use-mdx/